# Lowering functions to an embedded language

Tags: haskell, types, existential-type, gadt

How can I lower a Haskell function to an embedded language in as typesafe a manner as possible. In particular, let's assume I have a value type like

```
data Type t where
  Num  :: Type Int
  Bool :: Type Bool

data Ty = TNum | TBool deriving Eq

data Tagged t = Tagged (Type t) t deriving Typeable
data Dynamic  = forall t . Typeable t => Dynamic (Tagged t) deriving Typeable

forget :: Typeable t => Tagged t -> Dynamic
forget = Dynamic

remember :: Typeable b => Dynamic -> Maybe b
remember (Dynamic c) = cast c
```

and I want to convert a function like `(isSucc :: Int -> Int -> Bool)` to product of its dynamic form and some type information, like this

```
data SplitFun = SF { dynamic    :: [Dynamic] -> Dynamic 
                   , inputTypes :: [Ty] 
                   , outputType :: Ty
                   }
```

such that for some `apply` function

```
(\(a:b:_) -> isSucc a b) == apply (makeDynamicFn isSucc)
```

modulo some possible exceptions that could be thrown if the dynamic types actually don't match. Or, more explicitly, I'd like to find `makeDynamicFn :: FunType -> SplitFun`. Obviously that isn't a proper Haskell type and there's unlikely to be a way to pull the types from `isSucc` itself, so it might be something more like

```
anInt . anInt . retBool $ isSucc :: SplitFun
```

where `anInt` and `retBool` have `printf`-style types.

Is such a thing possible? Is there a way to simulate it?

Comment: Does [this](http://lpaste.net/91700) answer the question? If so, I'll write down an actual answer.

Comment: I'll try it shortly in the real code, but it looks good. Definitely a simpler path to it than I was following.

Comment: This works quite wonderfully! Please add it as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To implement a function of type `FunType -> SplitFun`, we'll use standard type class machinery to deconstruct function types.

Now, implementing this function directly turns out to be fairly hard. To get `inputTypes` and `outputType` from the recursive case, you have to apply your function; but you can only apply the function inside the `dynamic` field, which gives you no way to fill the other fields. Instead, we'll split the task into two: one function will give us the `Ty` information, other will construct the `[Dynamic] -> Dynamic` function.

```
data Proxy a = Proxy

class Split r where
    dynFun :: r -> [Dynamic] -> Dynamic
    tyInfo :: Proxy r -> ([Ty], Ty)

    split :: r -> SplitFun
    split f = let (i, o) = tyInfo (Proxy :: Proxy r)
              in  SF (dynFun f) i o
```

Now, `tyInfo` doesn't actually need the function, we use `Proxy` just to pass the type information without needing to use `undefined` all over the place. Note that we need `ScopedTypeVariables` to be able to refer to the type variable `r` from instance declaration. Clever use of `asTypeOf` might also work.

We have two base cases: `Bool` and `Int`:

```
instance Split Int where
    dynFun i _ = forget (Tagged Num i)
    tyInfo _ = ([], TNum)

instance Split Bool where
    dynFun b _ = forget (Tagged Bool b)
    tyInfo _ = ([], TBool)
```

There are no input types and since we already have a value, we do not need to ask for more `Dynamic` values and we simply return `Dynamic` of that particular value.

Next, we have two recursive cases: `Bool -> r` and `Int -> r`

```
instance (Split r) => Split (Int -> r) where
    dynFun f (d:ds) = case remember d :: Maybe (Tagged Int) of
        Just (Tagged _ i) -> dynFun (f i) ds
        Nothing           -> error "dynFun: wrong dynamic type"
    dynFun f []     = error "dynFun: not enough arguments"

    tyInfo _ = case tyInfo (Proxy :: Proxy r) of
         (i, o) -> (TNum:i, o)

instance (Split r) => Split (Bool -> r) where
    dynFun f (d:ds) = case remember d :: Maybe (Tagged Bool) of
        Just (Tagged _ b) -> dynFun (f b) ds
        Nothing           -> error "dynFun: wrong dynamic type"
    dynFun f []     = error "dynFun: not enough arguments"

    tyInfo _ = case tyInfo (Proxy :: Proxy r) of
         (i, o) -> (TBool:i, o)
```

These two need `FlexibleInstances`. `dynFun` examines the first `Dynamic` argument and if it's okay, we can safely apply the function `f` to it and continue from there. We could also make `dynFun :: r -> [Dynamic] -> Maybe Dynamic`, but that's fairly trivial change.

---

Now, there's some duplication going on. We could introduce another class, such as:

```
class Concrete r where
    getTy   :: Proxy r -> Ty
    getType :: Proxy r -> Type r
```

And then write:

```
instance (Typeable r, Concrete r) => Split r where
    dynFun r _ = forget (Tagged (getType (Proxy :: Proxy r)) r)
    tyInfo _ = ([], getTy (Proxy :: Proxy r))

instance (Typeable r, Concrete r, Split s) => Split (r -> s) where
    dynFun f (d:ds) = case remember d :: Maybe (Tagged r) of
        Just (Tagged _ v) -> dynFun (f v) ds
        -- ...

    tyInfo _ = case tyInfo (Proxy :: Proxy s) of
        (i, o) -> (getTy (Proxy :: Proxy r):i, o)
```

But this needs both `OverlappingInstances` and `UndecidableInstances`.